# How to include test category in visual studio test results

Tags: mstest, vstest, test-explorer, trx, test-results

How do I make sure the test categories I used in my unit tests are included in the test results. So that I could use the category to filter my tests or generate a html using trx2html grouped by the category.

[image]

```
[Trait("Category", "1")]
public class MyFeature1Tests

[Trait("Category", "2")]
public class MyFeature2Tests
```

I could see the tests grouped by the category in the visual studio test explorer. But it is not possible in the test results (.trx) file?

[image]